# Why two rows getting added to my SQLite database table?

Tags: c#, sqlite, .net-4.5

When I add data to my SQLite database table using the below code, it adds 2 identical rows to the table for some reason instead of one.

```
    using(SQLiteConnection conn= new SQLiteConnection(@"Data Source="+Path.GetFullPath("./TestDB.db")+";"))
    {
        conn.Open();

        SQLiteCommand command = new SQLiteCommand("INSERT INTO Test(FirstName, LastName, Age) VALUES('Chris','Pine',42)", conn);
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        
        SQLiteDataAdapter adap = new SQLiteDataAdapter(command);
        
        DataTable dt = new DataTable("Test");
        adap.Fill(dt);
        
        dataGrid1.ItemsSource=dt.DefaultView;
        adap.Update(dt);
        
        conn.Close();

    }
    
    MessageBox.Show("Complete!");
    refreshdata();
```

Why is this happening ?

Also, the code for refreshdata

```
public void refreshdata()
{
    
    using(SQLiteConnection conn= new SQLiteConnection(@"Data Source="+Path.GetFullPath("./TestDB.db")+";"))
        
    {
        conn.Open();

        SQLiteCommand command = new SQLiteCommand("Select * from Test", conn);
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        
        SQLiteDataAdapter adap = new SQLiteDataAdapter(command);
        
        DataTable dt = new DataTable("Test");
        adap.Fill(dt);
        
        dataGrid1.ItemsSource=dt.DefaultView;
        adap.Update(dt);
        
        conn.Close();

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling ExecuteNonQuery and you are giving the adapter an INSERT command in place of its `SelectCommand`.

```
SQLiteDataAdapter adap = new SQLiteDataAdapter(command);
```

That line of code uses a the constructor that sets the adapter's SelectCommand. When you `Fill()` the datatable, it calls the SelectCommand, but in your case it is an INSERT statement.

Really, you should not be doing anything with an Adapter there, you should just ExecuteNonQuery and then call `refreshdata`.

And you can remove the call to `Update()` in `refreshdata()`, it is not necessary.

Comment: I tried that but result is still the same

Comment: @Jayanta_KMC stand by, I will elaborate

Comment: @Jayanta_KMC does that make more sense?